# Excel Reference taking long time to load up

Tags: c#, excel

I have a reader funcction that reads Excel .xls file and returns DataSet.

Reading all the lines and returning a DataSet takes almost no time, but creating new instances of Excel Interop takes almost 2 seconds.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
//select first sheet from excel.
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wSheet = excelBook.Sheets.Item[1];
```

Passing those 3 lines takes 2-3 seconds, while reading 1000 lines of excel takes something like 0.03 seconds. Is there something that could be done?

Comment: oh come on. its only 2-3s. If you need to do this repeatedly just don't close the application object

Comment: Excel is a huge honking process.  Consider using one of the OpenXML-based libraries to read the spreadsheet directly.

Comment: @HansPassant Does OpenXML create dependencies? I honestly don't really like using Excel Interop in my projects, but it's kind of fast and "useful". What I've found out is that, to use the Excel Reference, I need to have the Office Excel installed as well. With out Excel installed it throws and error.

Comment: Libraries create dependencies.  Nothing that requires you to reformat your disk drive or download and install something on the user's machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the line

```
xlApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
```

Just after you instanciate `xlApp`. 
Don't forget to set it back to `true` at the end of the process.

It will slightly reduce running time.